# Using SSH, transfer a WebURL from local machine browser to remote machine on hard disk

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, command

Hi so i was doing some research in the library so i could use some pictures later on my Desktop computer in my room. I have space on my Lab account which i usually SSH into, and i was wondering if URL's can be directly transferred over to a remote machine and saved on the hard disk.

I was thinking something like this:

```
scp http://click.si.edu/images/truncatedurl.jpg /home3/etc.../filename.jpg
```

is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `wget` and `scp` together as such:

```
wget http://click.si.edu/images/truncatedurl.jpg -O file.jpg && scp file.jpg login@server:/home3/etc.../filename.jpg
```

The `-O` option allows you to name the output file and then you know which one you want to upload to your school's server.

Comment: i've had to install wget on since i  use a mac, and when i get to the step that requires me to "make install" i am not being able to get permission to /usr/local/bin/wget. I tried "chmod 777 <diectory>", and its saying that operation is not permitted. I understand you probably use Linux but if you have any idea, it would help.

Comment: @AlanTuring You tried to install `wget` locally to your Mac?  I found this link: http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/22/install-wget-mac-os-x/.  It sounds like you just need to be the super user by simply typing `sudo make install` instead.

Comment: right thanks, i realized that a minute after i posted that, but now it says "make[1]: Nothing to be done for `install.mo'." and wget is not being placed in usr/bin/

Comment: thanks i realized i could jsut wget from the remote machine, silly me.

Comment: basically i used, `wget <url> -O picture1.jpg` while ssh'd in and it worked fine. Thanks a lot bro, but i can't get wget on my machine yet, same reason as before "make[1]..."

Comment: @AlanTuring Absolutely, glad I could help.

Comment: curl and GET are to other open source programs I expect to be on the Mac. There is also the age-old lynx as well.